# Why LCD 16x2 cannot display "water leaking" when rain sensor detects water?

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors, lcd

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
SoftwareSerial mySerial(0, 1);

int gas_sensor = A5;
int water_sensor = 8;
int buzzer = 9;
int fan = 13;
int sms_count = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(gas_sensor, INPUT);
  pinMode(water_sensor, INPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(fan, OUTPUT);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(water_sensor) == LOW && analogRead(gas_sensor)) {
    CheckWater_and_Gas();
  }
  else if (digitalRead(water_sensor) == LOW) {
    CheckWater();
  }
  else if (analogRead(gas_sensor)) {
    CheckGas();
  }
  else {
  }
}

void CheckWater_and_Gas() {
  int sensorValue = analogRead(gas_sensor);
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  delay(1000);
  if ( digitalRead(water_sensor) == LOW && sensorValue > 150 ) {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(fan, HIGH);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print(" Water and ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(" Gas Leaking ! ");
    SetAlertWater_and_Gas();
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    digitalWrite(fan, LOW);
    lcd.clear();
  }
}

void CheckWater() {
  if ( digitalRead(water_sensor) == LOW ) {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(" Water Leaking ! ");
    SetAlertWater();
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    lcd.clear();
  }
}

void CheckGas() {
  int sensorValue = analogRead(gas_sensor);
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  delay(1000);
  if (sensorValue > 150) {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(fan, HIGH);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Gas Leaking !");
    SetAlertGas();
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    digitalWrite(fan, LOW);
    lcd.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you know that the rain sensor is detecting water?

Comment: i check it from online

Comment: actually i can detect water using this sensor but lcd cannot display 'water leaking' if i use the code

Comment: please format your code ..... select all of the code and click `{}` button

Comment: leave everything connected and load an LCD "Hello World" sketch ..... does it work?

Comment: i think lcd should be no problem because lcd can display gas leaking when mq6 gas sensor detects lpg gas. lcd can display water and gas leaking also when mq6 gas sensor and rain sensor detect lpg gas and water simultaneously. but i don't know why it cannot display water leaking when rain sensor detect water.

Comment: I guess `analogRead(gas_sensor)` is never zero so the first `if` is activated if `digitalRead(water_sensor)` is LOW

Comment: yep, it always has value

Comment: and is it the problem? that it shows "Water and Gas Leaking"?

Answer (score 1):

You schould start searching the root cause for your error: code, display, sensor, … step by step.

Check if your display is working by 1.) reducing your loop() to

```
void loop() {
    CheckWater();
}
```

and 2.) change

```
void CheckWater() {
  if ( digitalRead(water_sensor) == LOW ) {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    ...
```

to

```
void CheckWater() {
  if ( true ) {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
   ...
```

This allows you to check if your LCD is working properly. If not, start looking for the fault in wiring or maybe you are using a different LCD which has to be setup in a different mode as the sketch from online.

If this works, search for the rootcause in the sensor. Go back to the orignial code and put the input of the rain sensor to low. If your display shows: Water Leaking! something with your water sensor or it's Connection to your board seems to be wrong.

Comment: i will try it, thanks for answering me.

Comment: fine. if you gone through this, please edit your question adding the results and refining the question